# Matriz hexagonal em Python

Tags: python, matriz, grid

Gostaria de saber como poderia retornar os números de um vetor de vetores (matriz) dentro de um R (raio) específico usando Python.

Segue em base esta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguindo o vetor utilizado:

```
mapa = [
    [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
    [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6],
    [2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6],
    [3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6],
    [4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 0.6],
    [5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6],
    [6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6]
]
```

Usando o nó da linha 3 e coluna 3:

Temos as respectivas saídas

Em R = 0:

```
[3.3]
```

Em R = 1:

```
[2.2, 2.3, 3.2, 3.4, 4.2, 4.3]
```

Em R = 2:

```
[1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 3.5, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4]
```

Se ainda usássemos um R = 3 teríamos as saídas:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4]
```

Eu tinha feito um código esdrúxulo para aprendizagem retornando em forma retangular se ajudar (https://github.com/MuriloChaves/Kohonen_Fausett/blob/master/vizinhanca/codigos/vizinhos_bidimensional_retangular.py)

Comment: Uma matriz hexagonal é idêntica a uma "quadriculada", o que muda é o cálculo de distância das coordenadas> Ao processar as distâncias você tem que tratar as diagonais da direita (ou só da esquerda) da mesma forma que a vertical, ou subtrair/somar um offset de um dos eixos ao calcular as distancias a cada linha par (ou impar, depende de como organizou).Não se esqueça que o Y (no caso do seu gráfico) não vale 1, tem que calcular a distancia da diagonal, e somar com o offset horizontal (quando houver) * fator horizontal.

Comment: PS: No seu caso dá pra simplificar usando só offset, se for só pra determinar hexágonos concêntricos (sem calcular distância real)

Comment: A ordem da rotação (e do início) importa? Ou posso pegar a partir de qualquer ângulo em qualquer direção?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você mesmo pode perceber, por dentro do Python, você não vai usar uma "matriz hexagonal" - vai usar uma estrutura bidimensional mesmo.

O que você precisa é uma forma de (1) percorrer as coordenadas interessantes para você (no caso o tal do hexagono) e (2) mapear essas coordenadas "em cima do hexagono" para números na matriz retangular.

Para gerar as coordenadas "hexagonais" dado um centro e o 
número do raio, uma técnica pode ser trabalhar com um offset de ".5" para as linhas impares, e arredondar o valor na hora de mapear para os dados na estrutura retangular.

Então, dá pra pensar em gerar as coordenadas para 6 segmentos de reta - podemos colocar num "for" os 6 segmentos como direções. Para cada anel R, achamos a coordenada no canto superior esquerdo, e percorremos as 6 direções em sequência a partir daí. Para obter os dados na ordem que você apresenta, é só ordenar cada coordenada priorizando a linha e em seguida a coluna em ordem crescente - isso é possível com o uso do parâmetro "key" na função "sorted" do Python: usamos uma função que recebe uma coordenada, e retorna ela como uma tupla "linha, coluna" - essa tupla é usada como comparação na ordenação das coordenadas.

```
def normaliza(coord):
    return int(coord[0]), int(coord[1])

def extrai_coords(centro, r):
    if r == 0:
        return [centro]
    cx, cy = centro
    if cy % 2 == 0:
        cx += .5
    cursor = [cx - r / 2, cy - r]
    coords = []
    for direcao in [(1, 0), (.5, 1), (-.5, 1), (-1, 0), (-.5, -1), (.5, -1)]:
        for i in range(r):
            coords.append(normaliza(cursor))
            cursor[0] += direcao[0]
            cursor[1] += direcao[1]
    return coords


def extrai_dados(mapa, coords):
     return [mapa[coord[1]][coord[0]] for coord in sorted(coords, key=lambda c: (c[1], c[0]))]
```

No prompt interativo, usando o mapa que você passou, esse trecho de código da as mesmas saídas que você espera:

```
In [17]: extrai_dados(mapa, extrai_coords((3,3), 2))
Out[17]: [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.4, 3.1, 3.5, 4.1, 4.4, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4]
```

Por fim, note que essa é a solução para pegar aneis concêntricos em hexágono, não os dados num raio "R" redondo - para matrizes maiores há diferença. 
Também, se seu problema depende mito dessa geometria, vale a pena colocar isso numa classe, e especializar tanto o `__repr__` quanto os `__getitem__` e `__setitem__` da classe, de forma que você possa pensar direto nesse mapeamento que permite os hexágonos, e não tenha que se preocupar com as "coordenadas não inteiras" em cada operação.